# Method not returning value

Tags: java, switch-statement, return, return-type

Here is my method:

```
public int power(int x, int n) {    
    switch (n) {
        case 2: return square(x);
        case 3: return cube(x);
        case 4: return hypercube(x);
    }            
}
```

Compiler is displaying this message:

> Method breakpoint:Tester [entry] - power(int, int) - This method must return a result of type int" message.

Can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

I know it's bad practice, but I've been instructed not to store values in a local variable and return it at the end.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what do you think happens if n != 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: Your program won't return anything given an input for `n` of anything other than 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: "I know it's bad practice, but I've been instructed not to store values in a local variable and return it at the end." - You know what's bad practice? The only thing I see here that's bad practice is the error highlighted by the compiler error. Possibly you should have a `default` case that throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I tried using  a default case, but the same message remained.

Comment: Well it won't if your `default` case terminates the method, either by returning or throwing an exception. Unfortunately, you haven't shown us your code that includes the `default` case...

Comment: Martin: without seeing what you're doing wrong with your default case, then your error there is anyone's guess.

Comment: Ok, got it! I was just breaking from the case as opposed to returning a value.

Comment: there is no default case, not all cases are covered

Answer (score 4):

If `n`is other than one of your cases, nothing will be returned - that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Since your implementation only caters for n being 2, 3 and 4, the most appropriate thing to do is throw an exception:

```
public int power(int x, int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 2: return square(x);
        case 3: return cube(x);
        case 4: return hypercube(x);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Power must be 2, 3 or 4. Unsupported power: " + n);           
}
```

The compiler will then be satisfied that all code paths either return something or an exception is thrown.

Comment: you forgot the 'throws' statement. +1 for the thought; I never knew that throwing an exception could substitute a `return`.

Comment: @jdev `IllegalArgumentException` being a `RuntimeException` does not need to be declared as being thrown, and generally speaking is not declared in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `default` **case** to your `switch` :

```
case ...: 
    return ...
...
default:
    return 0; // return some default value in case no other case was executed
```

Note that the `default` case **must return an Integer**, otherwise the error shall persist.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int power(int x,int n){

switch (n) {
case 2:  return square(x);

case 3:  return cube(x);

case 4:  return hypercube(x);

}
return 0;
```

}

I guess it's because you don't have main return state. switch case can be bypass if n doesnt initialized correctly but compiler need return value if you define power as a int power () ...
If it return 0 you will know n isn't initialized well

Answer (score 0):

You must add default case or return after switch (because Java didn't what retuns if n isn't 2, 3 or 4):

```
public int power(int x,int n){

    switch (n) {
    case 2:  return square(x);

    case 3:  return cube(x);

    case 4:  return hypercube(x);

    }            
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
public int power(int x,int n){

    switch (n) {
    case 2:  return square(x);

    case 3:  return cube(x);

    case 4:  return hypercube(x);

    default: return 0;
    }                
}
```